# Google app script "Click to authorize" does not work

Tags: google-apps-script

Just finished writing my app with google app script. embeded it on https://sites.google.com/site/1000eventz/home but when someone else clicks the click to authorise, sends an email but doesnt load, what could be the problem? 
My settings>> Execute the app as : User accessing the app, Execute the app as:Anyone

Comment: could you show the code you are using ? what services does the script use ? what does it do ?

Comment: The code is here: https://script.google.com/d/1H6DLb8L6Qd3g55Dzn_A7ed61QvM_OcrLINDfya1i1h7JAyV_jLH7nmcq/edit Now clicking to authorise just makes the app script gadget disappear. Could it be a google sites bug or what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested a copy of your script and I have an authorization screen like this :

[image]
which is normal... and then the app seems to work normally as well. (my authorization is in french because I tested it on a french account ;-)

You could test the copy [on this link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw3GIJXnjLcophfWTiQsIDaDJx8Q0qlqtyke-Ims4QfVGanJoU/exec) , the app seems a bit strange in its presentation but I didn't want to debug it ... at least it works...

[image]

EDIT : I just tested on your site and it works if I right click the 'authorize' and 'open in a new tab', otherwise it doesn't indeed ! it seems that the browser fails to open another window. (tested on chrome & safari).

But the workaround you've set up on your page works well (the *click here to authorize* link) so I guess the problem can be considered as partially solved ;-)

I also saw your other posts and it seems that you still have quite a few issues to solve or to work around... I wish you good luck with that ;-)

note : *the button validation was a good idea, you should try to get it to work using Sriks answer on the other post (suppress setformat).*

Comment: I get your, Serge. The app does authorize when accessed standalone but when on a google site, it doesnt. why??? Try it here>> https://sites.google.com/site/1000eventz/home Check out the new script too: https://script.google.com/d/1H6DLb8L6Qd3g55Dzn_A7ed61QvM_OcrLINDfya1i1h7JAyV_jLH7nmcq/edit

Comment: see edit, I placed this comment here even if it concerns also other posts ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, seems ill have to move the whole service to the google site coz i hear apparently i cant embed a map or a calender on the standalone app. On Srik's post, the setformat on the datebox is essential in making the app super-easy to use, so I wont suppres. Cheers though.